# C++ Switch Statement inputs

Tags: c++, switch-statement, do-while

I am writing a C++ program that prompts the user for an input and then keeps track of how many times that input is entered.  I am currently using a do-while loop and a switch statement.  The part I am having trouble with is the switch statement.  I can't figure out how to keep track of how many times an input is entered.  For example:

```
Enter Value: 4
Enter Value: 4
Enter Value: 4
Enter Value: 3
Enter Value: 3
```

// I then want the program to be able to know and then eventually output, how many times the number '4' and '3' were entered.
I thinking possibly using some sort of increment counting form, but not 100% sure.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a `std::map<int,int>`. Here's why.

Let's look at alternatives, starting with the obvious:

```
int count0;
int count1;
int count2;
int count3;
int count4;

...

switch(input) {
case 0: ++count0; break;
case 1: ++count1; break;
case 2: ++count2; break;
case 3: ++count3; break
case 4: ++count4; break;
}
```

This does what you ask: you evaluate the input, and keep track of the number of times that specific input has been seen. This form does suffer from many problems:

- It requires one line of source code for each alternative. This becomes a problem when the user can enter any value, say, from 0 to 10,000!
- It has duplicate, virtually identical lines.
- It has many variables, each of which has to be entered independently, but uses identically.

We can reduce the variable count by specifing an array:

```
int count[5];
...
switch(input) {
case 0: ++count[0]; break;
case 1: ++count[1]; break;
case 2: ++count[2]; break;
case 3: ++count[3]; break;
case 4: ++count[4]; break;
}
```

This still suffers from too many almost-but-not-quite identical lines of code. Let's try to get rid of the switch statement:

```
int count[5];
...
++count[input];
```

Ah, now we are getting somewhere! By eliminating the `switch` statement, we have one easily-maintained line of code. But what if the user (accidentally or maliciously) enters a 6? Then we will increment `count[6]`, which does not exist. This is a Bad Thing. We could increase the size of the array:

```
int count[50000];
...
++count[input];
```

Now we are safe from the user. If he enters a 6, the Bad Thing no longer happens. Uh-oh, what about if the user enters 51000? We will increment `count[51000]` which does not exist. It should be obvious that we can't win this game -- for any number we choose, the user might choose that number plus 1.

Even if we could win, we'd still lose. If we are only asking the user to enter a few numbers, then we will have wasted the other 49,997 entries in the arary.

Fortunately C++ has a data structure that we can use which:

- can take arbitrary numbers as its range, and
- is space-efficient (compared to a large wasted array).

That data structure is called a map:

```
std::map<int,int> count;
...
++count[input];
```

A map is sort of like an array, but grows itself in a special way. Only the entries that we use are ever allocated, and every entry that we use is automatically allocated.

Comment: Adams: Thanks alot! Well articulated!

Answer (score 5):

```
std::map<int, int> frequency;
int value_entered_by_user = f();

frequency[value_entered_by_user]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your range of input values is limited, you can use an array. Each element of the array represents an input value. Initialize the elements to 0 at the beginning and increment the appropriate element when its corresponding input value is entered.

Comment: Or use a map to avoid wasting up to 8,589,934,588 bytes.

Comment: is there a way to do it with a switch statement? and how would I increment using an array?

Comment: What a smart-ass response, Tomalak. Where in my answer did you get the idea that I was suggesting allocating an 8gig array? The question being asked indicates an inexperienced programmer, who, I'd be willing to bet, hasn't yet learned about the STL yet or about maps. While your answer is a valid one, it probably isn't an appropriate one in this instance.

Comment: If you use a dense array, where "each element of the array represents an input value", since the OP specified no range limitations then you possibly need an array with 2,147,483,647 elements (the number of values an `int` can store). Then, assuming that the array's base-type is `int`, that's usually 4 bytes, for a total of 8GB. 16GB on a 64-bit system. Good luck with that. A sparse container is _clearly_ superior here, whether the OP has used the _C++ Standard Library_ (the STL is not relevant) before or not. Now would be a great time for him or her to gain that experience.